# Possible equation of a helix like curve with axis as tangent vector of another curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking for a parametric equation of a curve with certain helix like attributes. A helix is generated by the rotational and translational motion of a line along a fixed axis. But if I were to allow the axis itself to rotate, what would happen??

One example I had in mind was taking the tangent vectors of a second space curve as different positions of the rotating axis. The position vector of the original curve maintains a fixed distance from the position vector of the second one.  But I am not sure whether the two notions are the same.

In terms of curvature and torsion functions, the helix has 
$$\kappa = \dfrac{ \cos^2(\theta)}{r^2},\;\;\;\; \tau = \dfrac{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{r^2}$$

respectively where $\theta$ is the constant angle made by the tangent vector of the helix with the axis. In my case, I am looking at $\theta$ to be a $\mathbf{non-constant}$ function of say, arc-length $s$ i.e. $\theta(s)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Basis}{\mathbf{e}}\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$If $c$ is a (sufficiently smooth) curve in $\Reals^{3}$ and if $\Basis_{1}$ and $\Basis_{2}$ are orthonormal unit normal vector fields along $c$ (that is, $\Brak{c'(s), \Basis_{j}(s)} = 0$ and $\Brak{\Basis_{i}(s), \Basis_{j}(s)} = \delta_{ij}$ for all $s$), then for a sufficiently small $r > 0$ and a sufficiently smooth function $\theta$, the curve
$$
h(s) = c(s) + r\bigl(\Basis_{1} \cos \theta(s) + \Basis_{1} \sin \theta(s)\bigr)
$$
is a curve of the type you want (assuming I understand the question).

A couple of natural ways to construct fields $\Basis_{j}$ come to mind:

1. If $c$ has non-vanishing curvature at each point, you could take $\Basis_{1}$ to be the [principal normal field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas), and $\Basis_{2} = \frac{c'}{\|c'\|} \times \Basis_{1}$ to be the binormal field.
2. If $c'$ is never parallel to the $(x, y)$-plane, you could define $\Basis_{j}(s)$ by doing [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) on the ordered triple with elements $c'(s)$, $1, 0, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0)$.

   Generally, if $c'$ is never parallel to some plane $P$ through the origin, you could fix an orthonormal basis of $P$ and do Gram-Schmidt as in the preceding paragraph.

Here's a curve of the first type: The "core" (black) is a right circular helix equipped with its Frenet frame; the blue curve winds around the helical core with variable pitch.

[image: A variable-pitch helix around another helix]

Comment: Thanks!! The equation looks similar to those ribbon or tube constructions, right??

Comment: Also, would the various axis of the osculating helices , defined for sufficiently smooth curves also work as the varying axis for my curve?I am not sure whether I have phrased that question well.

Comment: Yes, this family of curves is very closely related to the tube of radius $r$ about a core (or axis) curve $c$. I'm not entirely sure about your second comment. The proposed formula views the axis as curved rather than thinking of a point winding in a helix about a rotating line; these two perspectives are equivalent in the sense that a curve described in one way can (in principle) be described in the other.

Comment: Thanks,  that's quite clear.  I  suspected my second comment was quite vague.  Your answer has been very helpful.